# How do remove URL from selected text from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have copied text from my webpage , the selected copied text are

```
var someText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec lorem eu ante ullamcorper semper. In venenatis augue sed dolor tincidunt aliquet. Quisque aliquam consectetur nunc eu congue. Ut aliquet nunc a vulputate ullamcorper. Fusce posuere nec tortor eget varius. Aenean blandit ultricies posuere. - See more at: https://mywebaddress.com#sthash.pUpdg9k4.dpuf";
```

I want to get rid of `see more at: url..` using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** and **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**:

```js
var someText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec lorem eu ante ullamcorper semper. In venenatis augue sed dolor tincidunt aliquet. Quisque aliquam consectetur nunc eu congue. Ut aliquet nunc a vulputate ullamcorper. Fusce posuere nec tortor eget varius. Aenean blandit ultricies posuere. - See more at: https://mywebaddress.com#sthash.pUpdg9k4.dpuf";
someText = someText.substr(0, someText.indexOf('-')); 
console.log(someText);
```